# React js onClick priority or UseState issues?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, function, frontend

i have problem with onClick function on element in React.

```
 const [selectedGenre, updateSelectedGenre] = React.useState("s");

  function update(genre) {
    updateSelectedGenre(genre);
    console.log(selectedGenre);
  }
  const Genres = (genreIds) => {
    return genreIds.map((genreId, index) => (
      <span
        style={{
          cursor: "pointer",
        }}
        onClick={() => {
          update(genreId);
        }}
      >
        {genreId}{" "}
      </span>
    ));
  };
```

When i click on span first time, console log of `selectedGenre` is "s",which is default. WHen i click second time, its updated. Why is it like that ? my `updateSelectedGenre` is before console.log.
Thank you very much.

Comment: Setting state is generally async so you won't necessarily see the change in state immediately. If you want to see the change after it happens use a `useEffect` with the state identified in the dependency array: `useEffect(() => console.log(selectedGenre), [selectedGenre]);`

Answer (score 0):

the setter in useState api is an asynchronous event, therefore you can not trust that calling console.log() will give you the new state.

The desired result can be achieved by

```
useEffect(() => {
    console.log(selectedGenre);
  },[selectedGenre]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Usually inside functions you can't console.log the state right after setting it, because something called as asynchrony, if you really wan't to log the change you should use useEffect

```
useEffect(() => {console.log(selectedGenre)},[selectedGenre])
```

Comment: You should recheck that line of code.